# java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse String as integer

Tags: java, android, exception, type-conversion

I was currently working on my android project when I came across this issue

I want this to convert a String like "0345303709"7 into an integer, but I keep getting a NumberFormatException.

I've searched all the questions here, but have not found a solution to my problem.

Below is my Android code:

```
 String edit_cell=cellnumber.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            if(cellnumber.getText().length()==11 && TextUtils.isEmpty(edit_cell)!=true && edit_cell!=null)
            {

                cell=Integer.valueOf("03462651882");
            }
            else
            {                   
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid CellNumber\n Write CellNumber like this Format:\nNetworkCode Followed by your Number\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(this, "eg:03213213214",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid cellnumber\n Write cellNumber line this format:\n Network code followed by your number\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "eg:03213213214",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
```

I am using eclipse Helios IDE and android version is 2.2 api 8

Comment: **Phone numbers are not number**.  You should store them as strings.

Comment: @Slaks i am validating the number for login If a user just entered a decimal number not a cellNumber then application would crash so I am doing this to validate.

Comment: Still a bad idea, you should use a regex to validate. It's also really annoying when applications force a format for phone numbers - just let users enter it however they want, strip out all non-digit characters and validate the length/prefix/whatever else.

Comment: try  cell=Integer.ParseInteger("03462651882"); instead of  cell=Integer.valueOf("03462651882"); this one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's too big for an Integer, you need a Long.

#### Edit

Didn't notice that it was a phone number - definitely store it as a String.

As for validation, *a lot* of people have dealt with that problem before.  See here, for example: [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @ Dmitri can you tell me the max limit of integer in Value I come from c# their we have int32,int64 so i never had this problem over their.

Comment: `Integer.MAX_VALUE == 2147483647` - it's a regular signed 32-bit int.

Answer (score 5):

That's because the value is too much for an integer to handle. The maximum value an integer can handle is 2147483647, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

You can use `long` (`Long.valueOf()`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

maximum value an integer is 2^31-1 < 3 462 651 882, so you must use long type.

Answer (score 1):

Because of higher value for `Int` you are getting

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "03453037097"`

Just replace the int value with long as like this

```
String edit_cell=cellnumber.getText().toString();
    try
    {
        if(cellnumber.getText().length()==11 && TextUtils.isEmpty(edit_cell)!=true && edit_cell!=null)
        {

            cell=Long.parseLong("03462651882");//=====> Change is here
        }
        else
        {                   
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid CellNumber\n Write CellNumber like this Format:\nNetworkCode Followed by your Number\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "eg:03213213214",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid cellnumber\n Write cellNumber line this format:\n Network code followed by your number\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "eg:03213213214",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
```